# Differents between deployment using WebLogic Server's tools and using Eclipse intergration?

Tags: deployment, eclipse-plugin, weblogic

According to this document: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/deployment/understanding.html

> Weblogic Server provides the following tools to help you configure and
>   deploy applications:
>
> ```
> weblogic.Deployer
> Administration Console
> WLST
> Deployment Tools for Developers
> ```

But we  still can run and deploy application directly on Eclipse by installing plugins like this:
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/oracle-weblogic-server-tools-kepler#.U7YXL7EbZZJ

So what the different between these methods ?
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation tells you exactly what the difference is... Do you have further questions more than what it provides? The end result is the same, your application or library is deployed.

- weblogic.Deployer is command line, Java based
- Admin Console is GUI based
- WLST is script based (Jython)
- Deployment Tools for Developers is an ant task for weblogic.Deployer